# Хранение настроек

Tags: java, настройки

А где принято хранить настройки подключения к БД (путь, логин, пароль) в Java программах?

Администратор должен иметь возможность эти настройки изменить. Программы не имеют графического интерфейса. Одна программа демон, а вторая сервлет для TomCat.

Для демона можно поместить properties файл возле jar. А как быть с сервлетом?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Почитал про JNDI. Красиво. Оформишь ответ? А для демона решение нормальное?

Comment: Оформил. Для демона решение нормальное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервлету лучше получать DataSource через [JNDI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) из Tomcat и не заботиться самому о подключении к БД.